# how to play sound by clicking on hyperlink

Tags: javascript

```
<audio id='aclick'>
  <source src="audio/click.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

$(document).click(function(){
    if (click == 1) {
        document.getElementById("aclick").play();
    }
});
```

this works fine except on hyperlink.

I need to play the sound by clicking on any tag, including hyperlink.

Comment: What is the value of `click`? Where is it assigned? What happens when you click on a hyperlink (other than no sound playing)?

Comment: @Phil, default is 1. the same problem exists even without click variable

Comment: It doesn't work on hyperlinks because clicking on a hyperlink navigates to another page or reloads the current page. In both cases all JavaScript code stops running until the new page is loaded.

Comment: @Vivek, does that mean there is no solution?

Comment: It doesn't mean that there is no solution. You can use `event.preventDefault()` as mentioned in some of the answers. This will play the sound but the hyperlink will stop working. To work around, you need to write additional JS for redirecting the page after the sound is played in case of hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperlink tries to redirect you to the href. Stop it  using [`e.preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and play sound

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (click == 1) {       
        document.getElementById("aclick").play();
    }
});
```

Comment: in that case hyperlink doesn't work. I want the sound and then go to another page.

Comment: You need to queue the events in such a case. Because the sound will stop playing the moment your browser navigates to a new page. You might have to set up a small delay using setTimeout

Comment: @bonaca You can do window.open to the href after playing the sound.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Ans :**

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();                   // prevent default anchor behavior
    var goTo = this.getAttribute("href"); // store anchor href

    // do something while timeOut ticks ... 
    $("#aclick")[0].play();

    setTimeout(function(){
         window.location = goTo;
    },3000);       
});
```

---

**Previous ans :**

> call function on any click

```
 jQuery( 'body' )
    .click(function() {
        alert("");
        $("#aclick")[0].play();
        return false;
    });
```

> call function on any anchor tag click

```
jQuery( 'a' )
    .click(function() {
        alert("");
        $("#aclick")[0].play();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: it doesn't help